# Usage of fontgen loader in Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I need to use fontgen-loader (https://github.com/DragonsInn/fontgen-loader) in my new webpack 2 configuration. Settings from documentation doesn't work for me. I have it like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
     {
        test: /\.font\.(js|json)$/,
        use: "style!css!fontgen"
     }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That project has been inactive for some time, long before webpack 2 I believe.

This fork was created as an alternative and should be fine with webpack 2: https://github.com/jeerbl/webfonts-loader

> This repository has been dumped from DragonsInn/fontgen-loader since it wasn't updated since March 2016.